# Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Board & Card Games Stack Exchange](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Sacrificing to regenerate from Supreme Verdict](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12147/sacrificing-to-regenerate-from-supreme-verdict)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to play Ring of Valkas?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12113/how-to-play-ring-of-valkas)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Game of Thrones 2nd Ed vs 1st + Expansions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12117/game-of-thrones-2nd-ed-vs-1st-expansions)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Can abilities with a [Click] cost be used during a run?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12169/can-abilities-with-a-click-cost-be-used-during-a-run)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Question regarding strong 2c opening](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12053/question-regarding-strong-2c-opening)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How do I interrupt a loop after multiple iterations?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12274/how-do-i-interrupt-a-loop-after-multiple-iterations)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Does Cell Portal restart the run?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/does-cell-portal-restart-the-run)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What general approach should be taken opening hands with 3=1=4=5 and 1=3=4=5 shape?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/what-general-approach-should-be-taken-opening-hands-with-3-1-4-5-and-1-3-4-5-sha)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [When should I mulligan in Android: Netrunner?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12224/when-should-i-mulligan-in-android-netrunner)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Can we take "Death Company Tycho" in an army without a Death Company?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/can-we-take-death-company-tycho-in-an-army-without-a-death-company)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)